# Copying script, need advice on adding a loop back

Tags: powershell

I've created the following script to make it easier for my colleagues to copy data, but I want to create a loop back so it asks my colleagues if they wish to copy another user profile data. What commands would help me achieve this ?

```
$Start = Read-Host "Do you have the relevant information for the migration? {Y/N)"
if ($Start -match "[Yy]") {
    $Source = Read-Host "Source Location"
    $Destination = Read-Host "Destination Location" 
    $SourceUser = Read-Host "Source Username"
    $DestinationUser = Read-Host "Destination Username"

    Robocopy.exe $Source\Users\$SourceUser\Desktop $Destination\Users\$DestinationUser\Desktop /E
    Robocopy.exe $Source\Users\$SourceUser\Documents $Destination\Users\$DestinationUser\Documents /E
    Robocopy.exe $Source\Users\$SourceUser\Downloads $Destination\Users\$DestinationUser\Downloads /E
    Robocopy.exe $Source\Users\$SourceUser\Favourites $Destination\Users\$DestinationUser\Favourites /E
    Robocopy.exe $Source\Users\$SourceUser\Pictures $Destination\Users\$DestinationUser\Pictures /E
    Robocopy.exe $Source\Users\$SourceUser\Videos $Destination\Users\$DestinationUser\Videos /E
    Robocopy.exe $Source\Users\$SourceUser\Appdata\Local\Google $Destination\Users\$DestinationUser\Appdata\Local\Google /E
    Robocopy.exe $Source\Users\$SourceUser\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Signitures $Destination\Users\$DestinationUser\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Signitures /E
}

#Copying the Sage data including Backups
$reply = Read-Host -Prompt "Does the user use Sage? [Y/N]"
if ( $reply -match "[yY]" ) { 
     Robocopy.exe $Source\SageBackups $Destination\SageBackups /E
        Robocopy.exe $Source\ProgramData\Sage $Destination\ProgramData\Sage /E
} 

$EndScript = Read-Host -Prompt "Do you want to close this screen? [Y/N]"
if ( $EndScript -match "[nN]" ) {
    Exit
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a `do until` and put what you had into a function. The function is called if the user says "Y" and the program exits if they say "N". It will just ask over and over after each copy if you want to run another copy.

```
function CopyProfile(){
    $Start = Read-Host "Do you have the relevant information for the migration? {Y/N)"

    if ($Start -match "[Yy]") {
    $Source = Read-Host "Source Location"
    $Destination = Read-Host "Destination Location" 
    $SourceUser = Read-Host "Source Username"
    $DestinationUser = Read-Host "Destination Username"

    Robocopy.exe $Source\Users\$SourceUser\Desktop $Destination\Users\$DestinationUser\Desktop /E
    Robocopy.exe $Source\Users\$SourceUser\Documents $Destination\Users\$DestinationUser\Documents /E
    Robocopy.exe $Source\Users\$SourceUser\Downloads $Destination\Users\$DestinationUser\Downloads /E
    Robocopy.exe $Source\Users\$SourceUser\Favourites $Destination\Users\$DestinationUser\Favourites /E
    Robocopy.exe $Source\Users\$SourceUser\Pictures $Destination\Users\$DestinationUser\Pictures /E
    Robocopy.exe $Source\Users\$SourceUser\Videos $Destination\Users\$DestinationUser\Videos /E
    Robocopy.exe $Source\Users\$SourceUser\Appdata\Local\Google $Destination\Users\$DestinationUser\Appdata\Local\Google /E
    Robocopy.exe $Source\Users\$SourceUser\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Signitures $Destination\Users\$DestinationUser\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Signitures /E
            }

    #Copying the Sage data including Backups
    $reply = Read-Host -Prompt "Does the user use Sage? [Y/N]"
    if ( $reply -match "[yY]" ) { 
         Robocopy.exe $Source\SageBackups $Destination\SageBackups /E
            Robocopy.exe $Source\ProgramData\Sage $Destination\ProgramData\Sage /E
    } 
}


DO{
    Write-host "Would you like to copy a profile?" -NoNewline; $run = read-host

    If($run -match '[yY]'){
        CopyProfile
    }
    else{
        exit
    }
}until($run -match '[nN]')
```

I suspect you're loggin in as an admin and copying "other" profiles however if you are not you could also work in using `$env:USERPROFILE` for your source and username as well.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `while` instead of an `if`, and assign `$Start` at the end of your while statement:

```
$Start = Read-Host "Do you have the relevant information for the migration? {Y/N)"
while ($Start -match "[Yy]") {
    $Source = Read-Host "Source Location"
    :
    :
    $Start = Read-Host "Do you want to copy another user profile?"
}
```

Also, consider storing your locations as an array and using `Join-Path` - makes things a lot more readable and easier to maintain:

```
$Locations = @(
    'Desktop'
    'Documents'
    'Favourites'
    'Pictures'
    'Videos'
    'Appdata\Local\Google'
    '\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Signitures'
)

$Start = Read-Host "Do you have the relevant information for the migration? {Y/N)"
while ($Start -match "[Yy]") {
    $Source = Read-Host "Source Location"
    $Destination = Read-Host "Destination Location"
    $SourceUser = Read-Host "Source Username"
    $DestinationUser = Read-Host "Destination Username"

    foreach ($Location in $Locations) {
        Robocopy.exe (Join-Path $Source\Users\$SourceUser\ $Location) (Join-Path $Destination\Users\$DestinationUser\ $Location) /E
    }

    $Start = Read-Host "Do you want to copy another user profile?"
}
```